# android: moving shape/image with values from accelerometer

Tags: android, accelerometer

ive managed to get out the accelerometers values (x,y,z). Is there an easy way to make a circle move with those values? I would also like it to stop at the edges of the screen. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this (**note:** partially pseudocode):

```
public void onSensorChanged (int sensor, float[] values) {
    //adjust someNumber to desired speed
    //values[1] can be -180 to 180
    float xChange = someNumber * values[1];
    //values[2] can be -90 to 90
    float yChange = someNumber * 2 * values[2];

    //only move object if it will stay within the bounds
    if (object.xPos + xChange > 0 && object.xPos + xChange < xBorder) {
        object.xPos += xChange;
    }
    if (object.yPos + yChange > 0 && object.yPos + yChange < yBorder) {
        object.yPos += yChange;
    }
    //force a repaint of your surface here
}
```

Where:

- [`onSensorChanged`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorListener.html#onSensorChanged%28int,%20float%5b%5d%29) is a method that is called each time the accelerometer moves... I'm not sure whether you are using [SensorManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html), but it seems convenient for your scenario. Note that you must implement this method yourself.
- `object` is the circle you want to move.
- `xBorder` and `yBorder` are the maximum bounds for the object's movement. The minimum bounds are assumed to be 0 and 0, though you can use whatever you like.