# Android:How to move Ball on maze using accelerometer?

Tags: android

Am developing game in android i did maze and ball is moving on maze using keyboard but am tryng to move ball by using Accelerometer please help me.........

Thank You

Comment: Show some code that you've written. Show us part of it where you have problems. Ask more specific questions ?

Answer (score 3):

```
SensorManager manager = (SensorManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

if (manager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).size() != 0) {
    Sensor accelerometer = manager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).get(0);
    manager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
}
```

This will setup the Accelerometer and then...

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    accelX = event.values[0];
    accelY = event.values[1];
    accelZ = event.values[2];
}
```

Will listen for the changes you just need to make sure that the call you want to use implements `SensorEventListener`.

Comment: this will take image out of bounds of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good tutorial on this site:
http://www.anddev.org/accessing_the_accelerometer-t499.html

However I wouldn't use the accelerometer for this (otherwise you have to throw the device to move the ball) ;-) Have a look at this site: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorListener.html Try the sensor orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Using these imports and the tutorials below you should be able to get a jump on your problem.

```
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
```

A tutorial can be found [here.](http://blog.androgames.net/85/android-accelerometer-tutorial/)

You can also check this old [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690208/android-moving-shape-image-with-values-from-accelerometer).